# Apply predicate to a list of lists of different lengths

Tags: list, prolog, element, predicate

I need to apply my predicate to a list of lists. I heard maplist/3 might be able to do this but my lists within the list may vary in length and maplist likes all the same length lists.

Here is the predicate I need to apply to all lists in the list. It checks if any elements in another list in the same position are the same and if they are it returns false. Ex: compatible([1,2,3,4,5],[1,6,7,3,2]) would return false since the 1 matches in the 1st position. This predicate works for varying lengths of lists.

```
compatible([],_).
compatible(_,[]).
compatible([HA|TA],[HB|TB]) :-
    HA \= HB,
    compatible(TA,TB).
```

A sample lists of list might look like this:

```
[[3,4,6,6,7],[8,2,6,3,67],[7,4,7,4,3]],[[8,2,6,3,67],[7,4,7,4,3]]).

Let X and Y be the lists passed in.
where X=[[3,4,6,6,7],[8,2,6,3,67],[7,4,7,4,3]]
and Y=[[8,2,6,3,67],[7,4,7,4,3]]
```

I need to apply the predicate to the Y list only. How would I call compatible on the list of lists to do that (keeping in mind varying length).

*EDIT TO CLARIFY MORE:

So compatible would essentially be called like this

```
compatible([8,2,6,3,67],[7,4,7,4,3]).
```

from the above list (It is only being applied to the Y list of lists). It would return true here.

If I called compatible like this:

```
compatible([8,2,6,3,3],[7,4,7,4,3]).
```

It would fail because a 3 is the 5th element of both lists.

Comment: try `forall(select(L,LoL,Ls),maplist(compatible(L),Ls)))`

Comment: that put me in some sort of infinite loop, what is Ls?

Comment: Ls is LoL without L, and the code seems to work - but there is a closed paren to delete

Comment: I'm still confused what LS is in the context of question.

Comment: `?- LoL=[[8,2,6,3,67],[7,4,7,4,3]], forall(select(L,LoL,Ls),maplist(compatible(L),Ls)).` gives true

Comment: `?- LoL=[[8,4,6,3,67],[7,4,7,4,3]], forall(select(L,LoL,Ls),maplist(compatible(L),Ls)).` gives
false.

Comment: What are the entities you want to relate? Please give some concrete examples of goals that should succeed and goals that should fail.

Comment: Please show an actual example of what you want your call to look like with a list of lists and expected results. it's a bit confusing.

Comment: I added some edits for clarification.

Comment: If `Y = [A,B,C]` you want to express pairwise compatibility, `compatible(A,B), compatible(A,C), compatible(B,C)`, right?

Comment: Exactly! You are correct.